# Do theano support lmdb or hdf5 data?

Tags: theano

Now I have lmdb and hdf5 data for image classification. And I want to use theano to train some convnets. So do theano support lmdb or hdf5 data?

Answer (score 0):

Theano does not "natively" support any file format, input data must be in the form of lists or numpy arrays. You just need to load the data using another library and use it with Theano.

h5py is a popular library to read/write HDF5 files from python. LMDB also has python bindings so reading that kind of data should not be an issue with python.

Comment: sorry to reply so later. thank you for your answer. I have used h5py.